# This code is working everywhere except in safari

Tags: jquery, ios, css

I have a jquery function when I click on a `td` the background should change to blue and the font color should change to white

everything works in this jquery function except the .css part, but when I scroll down to the end and go back OR scroll up to the end and go back, it works!

P.S this problem only in ios safari, everything is working just fine in android

As you can see the selected seat appears below and disappear when you click again (js is working just fine but not .css part), check this :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1759j144kVXTQtiwy-e9TU4WTmXuSnmhX/view?usp=sharing

```
 $('td[class="seat"]').on('click', function() {
$(this).css('background-color', '#0388d1');
$(this).css('color', 'white');
});
```

Comment: You know, people discover these kind of bugs even on Desktop Chrome. You should seek technical support / bug report of Safari. It's less likely for you wanting to do anything other than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem , in css i used -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);

But actually if you want to rotate vertically you should use rotate3d(0,0,1,270deg);

Horizontally : rotateY(180deg) rotateX(180deg);